# Configure express to call external API in proxy.conf.json in production

Tags: javascript, angular, express, heroku

I have two apps running on heroku, myserverapi(spring boot) and client(Angular app). the server is running on myserver.heroku.com while the client is myclient.heroku.com currently my express server is only serving static files. I am new to express want to know how to make it access my proxy.conf.json file where I have declared the domain it should call. everything works fine locally with Cli but after deployment, it doesn't work.

proxy.Conf.json file below

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://mygramapi.herokuapp.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

And my express server.js

```
//Install express server
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/mygram'));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +'/src'));
});
console.log(app);
// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000);
```

my API's all start with /api eg /api/login, /api/signup etc
is there a comprehensive way of handling this 
thank you.

express-http-proxy has the solution but i have a few question about it, does it mean i delete the express.js file and how about my static files , im not sure to add this to my existing code, so im accessing both static files and api's

```
const url = require('url');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');

// New hostname+path as specified by question:
const apiProxy = proxy('https://myserverapi.heroku.com', {
    forwardPath: req => url.parse(req.baseUrl).path
});

app.use('/api/*', apiProxy);
```

how do make them all work

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

As you may know, `proxy.conf.json` can be used only for webpack dev server - this proxy configuration ignores when you've built the prod bundle and just serve it via express server. For your case, I can suggest to check this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy or try to setup nginx.

Comment: Yes this is a good solution could you see my updated question, how to add it to existing express as i am new to express